# Google Drive API Requesting Permission for Edit a File (PHP)

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, cakephp-1.3, google-sheets-api

How to send **Ask Permission** request for a spreadsheet owned by another user for edit using google drive api?

There is a user A who owner of the file F, and i want to send a request asking for permission from user A for edit file F via Google Drive API PHP...

Answer (score 0):

You cant.  There is no way for user A to even know what file id they are requesting access to.

If user A tries to access a file that they dont have access to they are going to get an error stating that they dont have access. User F is going to have to grant the user access first.  Then they will be able to access the file.

The mechanism within the Google drive web application that requests access to a file owned by another user is not something that is part of the google drive api.  The google drive api is simply a file store for a user.

Comment: If i have the id of file, then can't i request the permission for that file?? (Via **Google Drive API**)